# Suppress the plot and only get the result

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to align two signals to get the lag that gives me the best coefficient. I am using the `xcorr` function in matplotlib. I am only interested in `z` in the following code.

Is there a way to suppress the plot (I dont want the plot) and get only the result?

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import xcorr
z = xcorr([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], [0,0,0,0,1.], normed=False, maxlags=4)
lagsOut = list(z[0])  
corrCoeff = list(z[1])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.correlate`:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.]
corrCoef = np.correlate(x, y, 'full')
lagsOut = np.arange(-len(x)+1, len(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

`matplotlib` is a plotting module. If you don't want plotting, you're better off just using `numpy` directly. See [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)

In case you need anything more from `xcorr`, you can use `inspect.getsource` to see what it does. Here's a abridged dump:

```
def xcorr(self, x, y, normed=True, detrend=mlab.detrend_none,
          usevlines=True, maxlags=10, **kwargs):
        Nx = len(x)
        if Nx != len(y):
            raise ValueError('x and y must be equal length')

        x = detrend(np.asarray(x))
        y = detrend(np.asarray(y))

        c = np.correlate(x, y, mode=2)

        if normed:
            c /= np.sqrt(np.dot(x, x) * np.dot(y, y))

        if maxlags is None:
            maxlags = Nx - 1

        if maxlags >= Nx or maxlags < 1:
            raise ValueError('maglags must be None or strictly '
                             'positive < %d' % Nx)

        lags = np.arange(-maxlags, maxlags + 1)
        c = c[Nx - 1 - maxlags:Nx + maxlags]

        if usevlines:
            a = self.vlines(lags, [0], c, **kwargs)
            b = self.axhline(**kwargs)
        else:

            kwargs.setdefault('marker', 'o')
            kwargs.setdefault('linestyle', 'None')
            a, = self.plot(lags, c, **kwargs)
            b = None
        return lags, c, a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

as I answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897581/5122657
Sometimes we cannot use `numpy.correlate` because sometimes we need the maxlags parameter that is only provided by the `matplotlib.xcorr`. But I understand that if we put complex data type as the arguments into `matplotlib.xcorr` directly, we will get "casting complex to real datatype" warning when matplotlib tries to draw the plot. 
Below I modified the code from matplotlib, so it can be used as a standalone function.

```
<!-- language: python -->

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def xcorr(x, y, maxlags=10):
    Nx = len(x)
    if Nx != len(y):
        raise ValueError('x and y must be equal length')

    c = np.correlate(x, y, mode=2)

    if maxlags is None:
        maxlags = Nx - 1

    if maxlags >= Nx or maxlags < 1:
        raise ValueError('maxlags must be None or strictly positive < %d' % Nx)

    c = c[Nx - 1 - maxlags:Nx + maxlags]

    return c
```

Comment: FYI if you are correlating complex data vectors make sure to conjugate one of the input vector (sources [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/thread/4929/correlation-for-complex-number) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45675/why-do-we-need-to-conjugate-complex-signals-in-autocorrelation-and-cross-correla) )