# Partial convolution / correlation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, correlation, convolution

I'm doing the cross-correlation of two large numpy 1D arrays (actually, auto-correlation), which takes a long time.

However, I'm only interested in a small portion of the result. Is there a way to calculate only that specific part of the convolution, in order to speed things up?

Here's a mock example:

```
import numpy as np
a= np.sin( np.arange(0,12,0.001) )
conv= np.correlate(a,a,'full')
autocorr= conv[len(conv)/2:]
print autocorr[0:50]
```

The region I'm interested in is in the beginning (of `autocorr`), so I think I can't simply truncate the input arrays

Comment: There's [an open feature request for this in the numpy issue tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5978)

Comment: Do you really want the *beginning* of `np.correlate(a, a, 'full')`, or the middle?  If you are interested in small lags (plus or minus), you want the middle (as in the linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677241/how-to-limit-cross-correlation-window-width-in-numpy).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser As in the example, I need the beggining of the `autocorr` variable, which is the middle of np.correlate. I've edited  the question to make that more clear, sorry about the ambiguity!

Comment: But in your code, `autocorr` is just the first `len(conv)/2` elements of `np.correlate(a, a, 'full')`, so it is still the beginning.

Comment: I guess you meant to do `autocorr = conv[len(conv)//2:]`  (I used `//` because in Python 3, `/` will give a floating point result.)

Comment: There are several answers in the question that this one duplicates, including one that I added yesterday that defines the functions `autocorrelation(x, maxlag)` and `crosscorrelation(x, y, maxlag)`.