# Fast way reduce noise of autocorrelation function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I can compute the autocorrelation using numpy's built in functionality:
`numpy.correlate(x,x,mode='same')`

However the resulting correlation is naturally noisy. I can partition my data, and compute the correlation on each resulting window, then average them all together to compute cleaner autocorrelation, similar to what `signal.welch` does. Is there a handy function in either `numpy` or `scipy` that does this, possibly faster than I would get if I were to compute partition and loop through the data myself?

## UPDATE

This is motivated by @kazemakase answer. I have tried to show what I mean with some code used to generate the figure below.

One can see that @kazemakase is correct with the fact that the AC function naturally averages out the noise. However the averaging of the AC has the advantage that it is much faster! `np.correlate` seems to scale as the slow `O(n^2)` rather than `O(nlogn)` that I would expect if the correlation was calculated using circular convolution via the FFT...

[image]

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345)
arparams = np.array([.75, -.25, 0.2, -0.15])
maparams = np.array([.65, .35])
ar = np.r_[1, -arparams] # add zero-lag and negate
ma = np.r_[1, maparams] # add zero-lag
x = sm.tsa.arima_process.arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, 10000)


def calc_rxx(x):
    x = x-x.mean()
    N = len(x)
    Rxx = np.correlate(x,x,mode="same")[N/2::]/N
    #Rxx = np.correlate(x,x,mode="same")[N/2::]/np.arange(N,N/2,-1)
    return  Rxx/x.var()

def avg_rxx(x,nperseg=1024):
    rxx_windows = []
    Nw = int(np.floor(len(x)/nperseg))
    print Nw
    first = True
    for i in range(Nw-1):
        xw = x[i*nperseg:nperseg*(i+1)]
        y = calc_rxx(xw)
        if i%1 == 0:
            if first:
                plt.semilogx(y,"k",alpha=0.2,label="Short AC")
                first = False
            else:
                plt.semilogx(y,"k",alpha=0.2)

        rxx_windows.append(y)
        
    print np.shape(rxx_windows)
    return np.mean(rxx_windows,axis=0)



plt.figure()
r_avg = avg_rxx(x,nperseg=300)
r = calc_rxx(x)
plt.semilogx(r_avg,label="Average AC")
plt.semilogx(r,label="Long AC")

plt.xlabel("Lag")
plt.ylabel("Auto-correlation")
plt.legend()
plt.xlim([0,150])
plt.show()
```

Comment: @CrazyIvan Sorry I have edited my answer - I do indeed use the `same` option.

Comment: You might find some help in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30677241/3670871

Answer (score 4):

**TL-DR:** To decrease noise in the autocorrelation function increase the length of your signal *x*.

---

Partitioning the data and averaging like in spectral estimation is an interesting idea. I wish it would work...

The autocorrelation is defined as

[image]

Let's say we partition the data into two windows. Their autocorrelations become

[image]

[image]

Note how they are only different in the limits of the sumations. Basically, we split the summation of the autocorrelation into two parts. When we add these back together we are back to the original autocorrelation! So we did not gain anything.

The conclusion is, there is no such thing implemented in numpy/scipy because there is no point in doing so.

Remarks:

1. I hope it's easy to see that this extends to any number of partitions.
2. to keep it simple I left the normalization out. If you divide *Rxx* by *n* and the partial *Rxx* by *n/2* you get `Rxx / n == (Rxx1 * 2/n + Rxx2 * 2/n) / 2`. I.e. The mean of the normalized partial autocorrelation is equal to the complete normalized autocorrelation.
3. to keep it even simpler I assumed the signal *x* could be indexed beyond the limits of 0 and *n*-1. In practice, if the signal is stored in an array this is often not possible. In this case there is a small difference between the full and the partialized autocorrelations that increases with the lag *l*. Unfortunately, this is merely a loss of precision and does not reduce noise.

> Code heretic! I don't belive your evil math!

Of course we can try things out and *see*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 2**16
n_segments = 8

x = np.random.randn(n)  # data

rx = np.correlate(x, x, mode='same') / n  # ACF
l1 = np.arange(-n//2, n//2)  # Lags

segments = x.reshape(n_segments, -1)
m = segments.shape[1]

rs = []
for y in segments:
    ry = np.correlate(y, y, mode='same') / m  # partial ACF
    rs.append(ry)

l2 = np.arange(-m//2, m//2)  # lags of partial ACFs

plt.plot(l1, rx, label='full ACF')
plt.plot(l2, np.mean(rs, axis=0), label='partial ACF')
plt.xlim(-m, m)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Although we used 8 segments to average the ACF, the noise level visually stays the same.

> Okay, so that's why it does not work but what is the solution?

Here are the good news: **Autocorrelation is already a noise reduction technique!** Well, in some way at least: An application of the ACF is to find periodic signals hidden by noise.

Since noise (ideally) has zero mean, its influence diminishes the more elements we sum up. In other words, you can reduce noise in the autocorrelation by using longer signals. (I guess this is probably not true for *every* type of noise, but should hold for the usual Gaussian white noise and its relatives.)

Behold the noise getting lower with more data samples:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for n in [2**6, 2**8, 2**12]:
    x = np.random.randn(n)

    rx = np.correlate(x, x, mode='same') / n  # ACF
    l1 = np.arange(-n//2, n//2)  # Lags

    plt.plot(l1, rx, label='n={}'.format(n))

plt.legend()    
plt.xlim(-20, 20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response, I have edited my answer a bit, im still testing out some stuff but of course you are correct in your analysis.

Comment: I can't argue with the Math, it seems pretty obvious now in retrospect so thank you! I did find that `np.correlate` is really slow on large data sets and that partitioning allows for much quicker computations. Not sure if youre finding the same?

Comment: @Jack Looks like [`numpy.correlate` is implemented as a loop over dot products](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1263), so your O(n^2) assertion seems to be correct. If you have large arrays, have a look at [`scipy.signal.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) which has an FFT based implementation.